# meteor.js and React - does the server rendering for SEO works out of the box?

Tags: meteor

I read some docs and still confused. It explains some technical details - like how you can inject something into `<head>` and `<body>` tags etc.

I don't quite understand it, it seems like you need to write some special code to make server side rendering work.

In next.js Server-Side Rendering works out of the box. I wonder if there's a similar way to make it works out of the box in Meteor.JS + React - without writing any additional special code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no out-of-box solution for SSR in Meteor. Meteor does have lots of Out-of-box features but SSR is not one of them.

You can read about how to do it in `Meteor + React` projects here.

https://docs.meteor.com/packages/server-render.html

**alternate option:**

You can use prerender for seo and we have good working product using Prerender in couple of my `Meteor + Blaze` projects.